# Fixed scrolling buttons

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for some sort of buttons that sticks with the users navigation to the right of some content that will also act as navigation.  Similar to hitting Page up or Page down.  Does something similar to this exist?  I imagine there's a jQuery solution but I can't find it.

Thanks!

Comment: A close example of what I want can be seen on https://www.banggood.com/ .. if you scroll down you will see some arrows that appear on the right.  They take you to the top or bottom of the page.  I want to create something similar but takes up up or down one frame at a time instead of straight to top or bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following css to maintain its fixed position.

```
position: fixed;
right: 10px;
top: 40%;
z-index: 100;
```

And then using jquery scroll function you can make scroll to top and bottom.

I have attached code here. Please check , let me know, if that helps.

```js
$("#spnUp").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 800);
});

$("#spnDown").click(function() {
  var overheight = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: overheight
  }, 800);
});
```

```css
.txt {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  max-height: 10px;
}
#scrl {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 100;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="txt">
  sdfsd sfs df sd fs df sd fsd f ds sdfsd sfs df sd fs df sd fsd f ds sdfsd sfs df sd fs df sd fsd f ds sdfsd sfs df sd fs df sd fsd f ds
</div>
<div id="scrl">
  <span id="spnUp"> Up</span>
  <br/>
  <span id="spnDown"> Dn </span>
  <div>
```